# Difficulty in implementing the neutron transport model

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on simulation of neutron transport model using monte carlo method. I'm first implementing the sequential algorithm that is given in the book  *parallel programming with openmp and MPI by M. J. Quinn*

The below (sequential) code given is a simulation of neutron transport model. when i run the executable file for the first time, it is running in infinite loop. When i stopped and ran again, the output i'm getting is 0, 0, 0 and is not the expected output for all possible values of input parameters, given in the question as mentioned in solution manual of M.J.Quinn parallel programming with openmp and MPI (Q.No 10.8).

The soft copy for the book is given below:
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/19aKs6XF3Gt6BRGSGVysZqam3Cb97rgRvTCYP2Nw-C5M/edit

*The expected output is: the amount of reflected, absorbed and transmitted rates are: 25.31, 46.13, 28.56.*  No error was given when the code was compiled. please help me out. here is the following code that i wrote:

```
struct neutron
{
    long double d    ;  // Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    long double x    ;  // Position of particle in plate(0<=x<=H)where H is the thickness of the plate
};
typedef struct neutron neutron;


int  main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double C ;   // mean distance between neutron/atom interactions is 1/C
    double C_s;  // Scattering component of C
    double C_c;  // Absorbing  component of C
    int r=0, b=0, t=0; //Counts of reflected, absorbed, transmitted neutrons
    int i=0;
    int n;                   // Number of Samples

    //double d;                //Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    int a;                   //a==0 implies false 1 otherwise
    double u;                // Uniform random number
    double L;                // Distance neutron travels before collision
    neutron nt;
    double H;
    double p,q,o;


    printf("\n Enter the value of C_s:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&C_s);
    printf("\nEnter the value of C_c:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&C_c);
    //printf("\nEnter the value of L:\n");
    //scanf("%lf",&L);
    printf("\nEnter the value of H (Thickness of the plate):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&H);
    printf("\n Enter the number of samples you want to simulate for....\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        u=rand()%n;
        u=1/u;
        nt.d=0;
        nt.x=0;
        a=1;
        while(a)
        {
            L=-(1/C)*log(u);
            nt.x=nt.x+L*cos(nt.d);
            if (nt.x<0)
            {
                //      printf("\nparticle %d got reflected\n",i);
                r++;
                a=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(nt.x>=H)
                {
                    //      printf("\n particle %d got transmitted\n",i);
                    t++;
                    a=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(u<C_c/C)
                    {
                        //      printf("\n the particle %d got absorbed\n",i);
                        b++;
                        a=0;
                    }
                    else
                        nt.d=u*(22/7);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    o=(r/n)*100;
    p=(a/n)*100;
    q=(t/n)*100;
    printf("\nthe amount of reflected, absorbed and transmitted rates are: %lf, %lf, %lf\n", o, p, q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) What _value_ is `C` as in `double C ; ... L=-(1/C)*log(u);`?  2) Suggest use `cosl(nt.d)` instead of `cos(nt.d)`.  3) Enable compiler warnings - saves you time.

Comment: As far as I can see you never initialize `C`.

Comment: Of topic: Always check the value returned by `scanf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
o=(r/n)*100;
```

which performs an integer division before the multiplication. Since your expected output is `25.31` that would mean the result of `r / n` should be `0.2531`, but the result of such an integer division is `0` which supports the `0` you are getting.

I suggest this

```
o = 100.0 * r / n
p = 100.0 * a / n;
q = 100.0 * t / n;
```

This will perform the correct arithmetic.

In addition you are using *uninitialised variables*.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one uninitialized variables so your code is UB (undefined behavior).

```
L=-(1/C)*log(u);
      ^
      uninitialized
```

Further, this looks strange:

```
while(a)
{
    ....
}
```

So `a` will always be zero when leaving the `while`. But still you do:

```
p=(a/n)*100;
```

which will cause `p` to be always zero. That is probably not what you want.

However, I see this line:

```
b++;
```

but I can't find any code where you are using `b`.

Did you really want to do it like this?

```
p=(b/n)*100;  // b instead of a
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistakes in my code by discussing with my classmates and rectified it and parallelized the code too here are the following  code:

```
/**
    To compile the program:         gcc sequential.c -lm
    To run the program:         ./a.out
**/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS 10000000                               //Total number of neutrons
#define SCATTERING_COMPONENT 0.7                                    // Scattering component of C
#define ABSORBING_COMPONENT  0.3                                    // Absorbing  component of C
#define THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE 8                                    //Thickness of the Plate
#define NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 1000
int no_of_particles_reflected=0, no_of_particles_absorbed=0, no_of_particles_transmitted=0;
double total_amount_absorbed,total_amount_reflected,total_amount_transmitted;
double distance_travelled_before_collision;                                     // Distance travelled by neutron before colliding from the plate
double C ;                                              // mean distance between neutron/atom interactions is 1/C
int flag= 1;                                                                                           int counter= 0;
struct neutron
{
    double d;                                           // Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    double x;                                           // Position of particle in plate(0<=x<=H),H is the thickness of the plate
};
struct neutron nt;
void neutron_model()
{
    double random_number_generator;                                         // Uniform random number generator
    total_amount_absorbed=0,total_amount_reflected=0,total_amount_transmitted=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;i++)
    {
        random_number_generator=rand()%TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;
        random_number_generator=1/random_number_generator;
        nt.d=0;
        nt.x=0;
        flag=1;
        while(flag)
                {
            distance_travelled_before_collision=-(1/C)*log(random_number_generator);
            nt.x=distance_travelled_before_collision*cos(nt.d);

            if (nt.x<0)
            {
                no_of_particles_reflected++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else if(nt.x>=THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE)
            {
                no_of_particles_transmitted++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(random_number_generator<(ABSORBING_COMPONENT/C))
                {
                    no_of_particles_absorbed++;
                    flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nt.d=random_number_generator*(22.0/7.0);
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)
                    {
                        no_of_particles_absorbed++;
                        flag=0;
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    C=SCATTERING_COMPONENT + ABSORBING_COMPONENT;   


    clock_t start, end;
    double diff_t;
    diff_t = 0.0;
    //start the clock
    start= clock();
    neutron_model();
    //stop the clock
    end = clock();
    diff_t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    total_amount_reflected=((double)no_of_particles_reflected/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
    total_amount_absorbed=((double)no_of_particles_absorbed/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
    total_amount_transmitted=((double)no_of_particles_transmitted/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;

    printf("\nDATA VALUE ASSUMED:-\n");
    printf("***********************************************************************\n");
    printf("TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS:  %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
    printf("SCATTERING_COMPONENT: %f\n",SCATTERING_COMPONENT);
    printf("ABSORBING_COMPONENT: %f\n",ABSORBING_COMPONENT);
    printf("THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE: %d\n",THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE);
    printf("***********************************************************************\n\n");
    printf("Total particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %d, %d, %d     \n",no_of_particles_reflected,no_of_particles_absorbed,no_of_particles_transmitted);
        printf("Percentage of particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %lf, %lf, %lf\n", total_amount_reflected, total_amount_absorbed, total_amount_transmitted);
    printf("Total time taken in sec %10.6lf\n",diff_t);
    return 0;
}
```

MPI version:

```
/**
    To compile the program:         mpicc -o neutron_transport with_MPI.c -lm
    To run the program:         mpirun -np <specify no. of processes> neutron_transport 
**/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<mpi.h>

#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS 1000                       //Total number of neutrons
#define SCATTERING_COMPONENT 0.7                            // Scattering component of C
#define ABSORBING_COMPONENT  0.3                            // Absorbing  component of C
#define THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE 4                            //Thickness of the Plate
#define NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 1000
#define BLOCK_LOW(id,p,n)   ((id)*(n)/(p))
#define BLOCK_HIGH(id,p,n)  (BLOCK_LOW((id)+1,p,n)-1)
#define BLOCK_SIZE(id,p,n)  (BLOCK_LOW((id)+1,p,n)-BLOCK_LOW(id,p,n))       //Block Size for each process

struct neutron
{
    long double d;                                  // Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    long double x;                                  // Position of particle in plate(0<=x<=H) where H is the thickness of the plate
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int process_id;                                 //Process Identifier
    int number_of_processes;                            //Number of Processes in the communicator
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);                              //Starting of MPI program
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&process_id);                  //Determine the process ID number in the communicator
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&number_of_processes);             //Determine the number of processes in the communicator
    int i=0;                                    //Loop iterator
    int counter=0;
    int buffer_share_for_each_process=0;
    double C ;                                      // mean distance between neutron/atom interactions is 1/C
    C=SCATTERING_COMPONENT + ABSORBING_COMPONENT;   
    int flag= 1;                                                    
    double random_number_generator;                                 // Uniform random number
    double distance_travelled_before_collision;                         // Distance travelled by neutron before collision
    struct neutron nt;
    double total_amount_absorbed,total_amount_reflected,total_amount_transmitted;
    int count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[3];
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]=0;
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]=0;
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]=0;
    int global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[3];
    buffer_share_for_each_process= BLOCK_SIZE(process_id,number_of_processes,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
    double elapsed_time1;                   //Timer variables
    elapsed_time1= -MPI_Wtime();
    if(number_of_processes > TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)
    {
        if(!process_id) 
            printf("Too many processes. Kindly provide lesser number of processes.\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=buffer_share_for_each_process;i++)
    {
        random_number_generator=rand()%TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;
        random_number_generator=1/random_number_generator;
        nt.d=0;
        nt.x=0;
        flag=1;
        distance_travelled_before_collision=-(1/C)*log(random_number_generator);
        nt.x=distance_travelled_before_collision*cos(nt.d);

        while(flag)
                {
            distance_travelled_before_collision=-(1/C)*log(random_number_generator);
            nt.x=distance_travelled_before_collision*cos(nt.d);

            if (nt.x<0)
            {
                count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else if(nt.x>=THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE)
            {
                count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(random_number_generator<(ABSORBING_COMPONENT/C))
                {
                    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]++;
                    flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nt.d=random_number_generator*(22.0/7.0);
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)
                    {
                        count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]++;
                        flag=0;
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i= 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++)
        MPI_Reduce(&count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[i], &global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[i], 1, MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) ; 
    elapsed_time1+= MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(!process_id)
    {
        total_amount_reflected=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
        total_amount_absorbed=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
        total_amount_transmitted=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;

        printf("\nDATA VALUE ASSUMED:-\n");
        printf("*****************************************************************************************\n");
        printf("TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS:  %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
        printf("SCATTERING_COMPONENT: %f\n",SCATTERING_COMPONENT);
        printf("ABSORBING_COMPONENT: %f\n",ABSORBING_COMPONENT);
        printf("THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE: %d\n",THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE);
        printf("TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSES: %d\n",number_of_processes);
        printf("*****************************************************************************************\n\n");
        printf("Total particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %d, %d, %d \n",global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0],global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1],global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]);
            printf("Percentage of particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %lf, %lf, %lf\n", total_amount_reflected, total_amount_absorbed,   total_amount_transmitted);
        printf("Total time taken in sec %10.6f\n",elapsed_time1);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

OpenMP version:

```
 /**
    To compile the program:         gcc -fopenmp with_open_mp.c -lm
    To run the program:         ./a.out
**/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS 10000000                               //Total number of neutrons
#define SCATTERING_COMPONENT 0.7                                    // Scattering component of C
#define ABSORBING_COMPONENT  0.3                                    // Absorbing  component of C
#define THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE 5                                    //Thickness of the Plate
#define NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 1000
#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS 500
struct neutron
{
    double d;                                           // Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    double x;                                         // Position of particle in plate(0<=x<=H) where H is the thickness of the plate
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double C ;                                              // mean distance between neutron/atom interactions is 1/C
    C=SCATTERING_COMPONENT + ABSORBING_COMPONENT;   
    int no_of_particles_reflected=0, no_of_particles_absorbed=0, no_of_particles_transmitted=0;
    int flag= 1;                                                    
    double random_number_generator;                                         // Uniform random number
    double distance_travelled_before_collision;                                 // Distance travelled by neutron before collision
    struct neutron nt;
    double total_amount_absorbed,total_amount_reflected,total_amount_transmitted;
    int counter= 0;
        srand(time(NULL));
    clock_t start, end;
    double diff_t;
    diff_t = 0.0;
    //start the clock
    start= clock();
    //int t=omp_get_num_procs();
    omp_set_num_threads(TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:no_of_particles_reflected,no_of_particles_absorbed,no_of_particles_transmitted)
    for(int i=1;i<=TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;i++)
    {
        random_number_generator=rand()%TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;
        random_number_generator=1/random_number_generator;
        nt.d=0;
        nt.x=0;
        flag=1;
        while(flag)
                {
            distance_travelled_before_collision=-(1/C)*log(random_number_generator);
            nt.x=distance_travelled_before_collision*cos(nt.d);

            if (nt.x<0)
            {
                no_of_particles_reflected++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else if(nt.x>=THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE)
            {
                no_of_particles_transmitted++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(random_number_generator<(ABSORBING_COMPONENT/C))
                {
                    no_of_particles_absorbed++;
                    flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nt.d=random_number_generator*(22.0/7.0);
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)
                    {

                        no_of_particles_absorbed++;
                        flag=0;
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //stop the clock
    end = clock();
    diff_t = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nDATA VALUE ASSUMED:-\n");
    printf("*****************************************************************************************\n");
    printf("TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS:  %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
    printf("SCATTERING_COMPONENT: %f\n",SCATTERING_COMPONENT);
    printf("ABSORBING_COMPONENT: %f\n",ABSORBING_COMPONENT);
    printf("THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE: %d\n",THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE);
    printf("TOTAL NUMBER OF THREADS: %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    printf("*****************************************************************************************\n\n");
    total_amount_reflected=((double)no_of_particles_reflected/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
    total_amount_absorbed=((double)no_of_particles_absorbed/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
    total_amount_transmitted=((double)no_of_particles_transmitted/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
printf("Total particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %d, %d, %d \n",no_of_particles_reflected,no_of_particles_absorbed,no_of_particles_transmitted);
        printf("The amount reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %lf, %lf, %lf\n", total_amount_reflected, total_amount_absorbed, total_amount_transmitted);
    printf("Total time taken in sec %10.6lf\n",diff_t);
    return 0;
}
```

Hybrid version of MPI and OpenMP:

```
/**
    To compile the program:         mpicc -fopenmp mpi_openmp.c -o hybrid -lm
    To run the program:         mpirun -np <specify number of processes> ./hybrid
**/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<mpi.h>

#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS 10000000                               //Total number of neutrons
#define SCATTERING_COMPONENT 0.7                                    // Scattering component of C
#define ABSORBING_COMPONENT  0.3                                    // Absorbing  component of C
#define THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE 3                                    //Thickness of the Plate
#define BLOCK_LOW(id,p,n)   ((id)*(n)/(p))
#define BLOCK_HIGH(id,p,n)  (BLOCK_LOW((id)+1,p,n)-1)
#define BLOCK_SIZE(id,p,n)  (BLOCK_LOW((id)+1,p,n)-BLOCK_LOW(id,p,n))               //Block Size for each process
#define NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 1000
#define TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS 500                                 //Total number of threads
struct neutron
{
    double d;                                           // Direction of the neutron (measured in radians between 0 and pi)
    double x;                                         // Position of particle in plate(0<=x<=H) where H is the thickness of the plate
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct neutron nt;
    int process_id;                                         //Process Identifier
    int number_of_processes;                                    //Number of Processes in the communicator
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);                                      //Starting of MPI program
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&process_id);                          //Determine the process ID number in the communicator
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&number_of_processes);                     //Determine the number of processes in the communicator

    double C ;                                              // mean distance between neutron/atom interactions is 1/C
    C=SCATTERING_COMPONENT + ABSORBING_COMPONENT;   
    int flag= 1;                                                    
    double random_number_generator;                                         // Uniform random number
    double distance_travelled_before_collision;                                 // Distance travelled by neutron before collision
    int no_of_particles_reflected=0, no_of_particles_absorbed=0, no_of_particles_transmitted=0;
    double total_amount_absorbed,total_amount_reflected,total_amount_transmitted;

    int counter= 0;
    int buffer_share_for_each_process=0;
        srand(time(NULL));

    int count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[3];
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]=0;
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]=0;
    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]=0;
    int global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[3];
    buffer_share_for_each_process= BLOCK_SIZE(process_id,number_of_processes,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
    double elapsed_time1;                   //Timer variables
    elapsed_time1= -MPI_Wtime();

    //int t=omp_get_num_procs();
    omp_set_num_threads(TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    if((number_of_processes) > TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)
    {
        if(!process_id) 
            printf("Too many processes. Kindly provide lesser number of processes.\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i=1;i<=buffer_share_for_each_process;i++)
    {
        //printf("Buffer_Share= %d by process %d (thread %d out of %d)\n",buffer_share_for_each_process,process_id,omp_get_thread_num(),omp_get_num_threads());
        random_number_generator=rand()%TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS;
        random_number_generator=1/random_number_generator;
        nt.d=0;
        nt.x=0;
        flag=1;
        while(flag)
                {
            distance_travelled_before_collision=-(1/C)*log(random_number_generator);
            nt.x=distance_travelled_before_collision*cos(nt.d);

            if (nt.x<0)
            {
                count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else if(nt.x>=THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE)
            {
                count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]++;
                flag=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(random_number_generator<(ABSORBING_COMPONENT/C))
                {
                    count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]++;
                    flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    nt.d=random_number_generator*(22.0/7.0);
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS)
                    {
                        count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]++;
                        flag=0;
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i= 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++)
        MPI_Reduce(&count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[i], &global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[i], 1, MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) ; 
    elapsed_time1+= MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(!process_id)
    {
        total_amount_reflected=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
        total_amount_absorbed=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;
        total_amount_transmitted=((double)global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]/(double)TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS)*100.0;

        printf("\nDATA VALUE ASSUMED:-\n");
        printf("*****************************************************************************************\n");
        printf("TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS:  %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_NEUTRONS);
        printf("SCATTERING_COMPONENT: %f\n",SCATTERING_COMPONENT);
        printf("ABSORBING_COMPONENT: %f\n",ABSORBING_COMPONENT);
        printf("THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE: %d\n",THICKNESS_OF_THE_PLATE);
        printf("TOTAL NUMBER OF PROCESSES: %d\n",number_of_processes);
        printf("TOTAL NUMBER OF THREADS: %d\n",TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        printf("*****************************************************************************************\n\n");
        printf("Total particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %d, %d, %d \n",global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[0],global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[1],global_count_of_reflected_absorbed_transmitted[2]);
            printf("Percentage of particles reflected,absorbed and transmitted respectively are: %lf, %lf, %lf\n", total_amount_reflected, total_amount_absorbed,   total_amount_transmitted);
        printf("Total time taken in sec %10.6f\n",elapsed_time1);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```